# Fourier transformation of the symmetric group $S_3$

Tags: finite-groups, fourier-analysis, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, quantum-computation

I am trying to compute the Fourier transformation of the symmetric group $S_3$ following the section 4 of [Quantum Computing and the Hunt for Hidden Symmetry](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/iui.inst.190/Mitarbeiter/toran/beatcs/column93.pdf).

The multiplication table of $S_3$ is as follows.

[image]

At this point I am supposed to come up with a representation $\rho : S_3 \to GL(V)$ where $GL(V)$ is the collection of invertible linear operators on a $\mathbb{C}$  vector space.

So, I choose $6$ $3 \times 3$ permutation matrices each corresponding to the permutation element because they are invertible.

All these matrices are irreducible.

Let $f$ be the function which maps the group elements to it's corresponding matrix as defined in $\rho$. We could have more interesting functions but I am trying to keep it simple.

So, the Fourier transform of $f$, $\hat{f}$ is given below.

$$
\hat{f} (\rho) =  \sqrt{\frac{d_\rho}{|S_3|}} \sum_{s\in S_3} f(s) \rho(s^{-1})
\\
=  \sqrt{\frac{3}{6}} \sum_{s\in S_3} f(s) \rho(s^{-1})
\\
=  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \left(  f(e) \rho(e^{-1}) + f((1,2)) \rho((1,2)^{-1}) + f((2,3)) \rho((2,3)^{-1}) + f((1,3)) \rho((1,3)^{-1}) + f((1,2,3)) \rho((1,2,3)^{-1}) + f((1,3,2)) \rho((1,3,2)^{-1})\right)
\\
=  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \left(  f(e) \rho(e) + f((1,2)) \rho((1,2)) + f((2,3)) \rho((2,3)) + f((1,3)) \rho((1,3)) + f((1,2,3)) \rho((1,3,2)) + f((1,3,2)) \rho((1,2,3))\right)
\\
= \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \left(  \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}  + \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\right)
\\
=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \sqrt{2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \sqrt{2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \sqrt{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

**My question:**

Did I do it right?